# How do we, by what means do we become "like Jesus"?

Tags: jesus

> <sup>2</sup>Beloved, now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet appear what we shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is.
>   -- 1 John 3:2 (KJV)

Various translations seem to indicate that we will not be like Jesus until he returns to earth again and before we are taken up to heaven.

Any insights would be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to BH. The text you refer to states that 'we shall be like him ; for we shall see him as he is' [KJV]. I am not clear as to what sort of insights you are expecting above and beyond John's statement..

Answer (score 1):

**How do we, by what means do we become “like Jesus”?**

Since no man  has seen God ,no one knows his form, so the Apostle John under inspiration, wrote:

1 John 3:2 (YLT)

> 2 "Beloved, now, children of God are we, and it was not yet manifested
>   what we shall be, and we have known that if he may be manifested, like
>   him we shall be, because we shall see him as he is;"

What has not been made manifest to them is what they shall be like when they are resurrected to heaven with spirit bodies.

Philippians 3:20-21 (YLT)

> "20 For our citizenship is in the heavens, whence also a Savior we
>   await -- the Lord Jesus Christ ,21 who shall transform the body of our
>   humiliation to its becoming conformed to the body of his glory,
>   according to the working of his power, even to subject to himself the
>   all things."

"And we have known that if he may be manifested, like him we shall be, because we shall see him as he is:

2 Corinthians 3:17-18 (NASB)

> 17 "Now the Lord is the Spirit, and where the Spirit of the Lord is,
>   there is liberty. 18 But we all, with unveiled face, beholding as in a
>   mirror the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into the same
>   image from glory to glory, just as from the Lord, the Spirit."

The above refers only to those having the heavenly hope  " the chosen ones" (Mat. 24:31 YTL) or the "little flock",  as Jesus revealed, it will be a relatively small number of humans that will be selected and the assurance is "your Father is well pleased to give you the kingdom."(Luke 12:32)

Luke 12:32  (NET Bible)

> 32 “Do not be afraid, little flock, for your Father is well pleased[a]
>   to give you the kingdom."

Comment: Up-voted +1, but where do you get the idea of 'spirit-bodies' in resurrection ? I cannot find a scripture that expresses that. They shall not marry or be given in marriage, says Jesus. But that does not imply a non-physical resurrection.

Comment: Nigel J  Appreciate you comment. God’s Son. God’s “only-begotten son,” the Word, was a spirit person like his Father, hence “existing in God’s form” (Php 2:5-8), but later “became flesh,” residing among mankind as the man Jesus. (Joh 1:1, 14)  So if the chosen ones are going to be like him, they have to take a spirit form, Paul wrote flesh and blood cannot inherit the Kingdom of God. 1 Cor. 15:50 -54

Comment: Nigel J I believe your referring to Luke 20:27-36 . Jesus I think had in mind the Heavenly Resurrection and some verses that would be considered in such a reply are 2 Thes. 1:5,11. Rom. 5:1,18. 8:1 . Rev. 20:5-6. and 1 Cor. 15:53-54. In contrast to the earthly resurrection of unrighteous  Acts 24:15

Comment: @NigelJ - the whole life of Christian is to put aside the “psychical” mind and live by the Spirit (1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18).

Answer (score 0):

physically like Him when transfigured, like He is. Psychologically like Him when transformed, by beholding Him, enjoying and experiencing Him, especially as the person within us. Christ "making home in our hearts"; "he who eats Me shall live by Me"; we believers into Jesus as God, Lord, "are all given to drink one Spirit." This growth comes at a small expense (to us it may occasionally seem large) of "losing our soul-life for His sake." That is to mingle with the predominant One: God, Jesus our Lord, the Triune Spirit. Cf Romans 8 written by one who experienced these very things, about these very things

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it "appears" there is difficulty translating this passage based on the variance of translations. When you see a verse translated differently in different Bible versions, it tells you immediately that the translators are trying to discern how to move this into English. God willing, through this exchange, the answer will be "made known" to us.

Once the Greek is moved into English, then we have to determine what we mean by "when *Christ* appears" (NIV, the word Christ is not in the Greek.) or "when *Christ* returns" (CEV) or "when **he** is revealed" (NKJV).

Is the "appear" or "reveal" in the future? at the second coming? or is it when Christ's character is revealed to us - that we may see Him plainly and - become like him? **What will we be?**

Here are a few different versions:

> Dear friends, now we are children of God, and what we will be has not yet **been made known** (ἐφανερώθη ephanerōthē). But we know that when Christ **appears** (φανερωθῇ
>   phanerōthē), we shall be like him, for we shall see him as he is. (NIV)

-

> Beloved, we are God’s children now, and what we will be has not yet **appeared** (ἐφανερώθη ephanerōthē); but we know that when he **appears** (φανερωθῇ
>   phanerōthē) we shall be like him, because we shall see him as he is. (ESV).

-

> Beloved, now we are children of God; and it has not yet been **revealed** (ἐφανερώθη ephanerōthē) what we shall be, but we know that when He is **revealed** (φανερωθῇ phanerōthē), we shall be like Him, for we shall see Him as He is. (NKJV)

The two bolded words - the words in question - are variants of the same Greek word, φανερόω (phaneroó) which means: to make visible, make clear, or to make manifest. Notice the NIV translates them as "made known" and "appear" where the ESV (appear/appear)and the NKJV (revealed/revealed) are consistent in their word choice.

From [HELPS - Word Studies](https://biblehub.com/greek/5319.htm):

> 5319 phaneróō (from 5457 /phṓs, "light") – properly, illumine, make manifest (visible); (figuratively) make plain, in open view; to become apparent ("graspable").
>
> 5319 /phaneróō ("become manifest") in 1 Jn 3:2 1 Jn 3:2: "Beloved, now we are children of God, and it has not appeared as yet what we will be. We know that if (Gk ean) He becomes manifest (5319 /phaneróō), we will be like Him, because (hoti) we will see Him just as (Gk kathōs) He is."

The context of John 3 is your personal character. Righteousness and sin. The very next verse is about purifying yourself:

> And everyone who thus hopes in him purifies himself as he is pure. 1 Jn 3:3

This is not a text about what you will be like in heaven, but rather what should you be like today:

> Little children, let no one deceive you. Whoever practices righteousness is righteous, as he is righteous. 1 Jn 3:7

The remainder of 1 Jn 3 is the call to love one another. In order to authentically love one another, we are going to have to become "Christ-like" in our character.

Becoming "Christ-like" in our character is a lifelong process that can only be manifested through the power of the Holy Spirit. We cannot redeem ourselves. Redemption must always come from the outside.

Paul writes:

> And we all, who with unveiled faces contemplate the Lord's glory, **are being transformed into his image** with ever-increasing glory, which comes from the Lord, who is the Spirit.  (2 Cor. 3:18)

When the fullness of Christ's character is "made manifest" to us, and we are able to "see him as he is" then we are able to "be like him."

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>29</sup>For whom he did foreknow, **he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son**, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren. <sup>30</sup>Moreover whom he did predestinate, them he also called: and whom he called, them he also justified: and whom he justified, them he also glorified.
>   
>   <sup>31</sup>What shall we then say to these things? If God be for us, who can be against us?
>   *-- Romans 8:29-31 (KJV)*

Paul suggests here that God has known from the beginning (foreknew) who would respond positively to His invitation to come to Him. That is not to say that God predetermined who would come, only that those who do come, "***He did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son***".

Paul confirms this idea of conformation as a progressive process in Philippians, when he says:

> <sup>3</sup>I thank my God upon every remembrance of you, <sup>4</sup>Always in every prayer of mine for you all making request with joy, <sup>5</sup>For your fellowship in the gospel from the first day until now; <sup>6</sup>Being confident of this very thing, that **he which hath begun a good work in you will perform it until the day of Jesus Christ**:
>   *-- Philippians 1:3-6 (KJV)*

It seems an unreasonable outcome that the conformation process will mean that every saint will eventually look like Jesus. Rather, the process will refine each saint<sup>(1)</sup> so that as Jesus walked and talked during his life, so they will learn to walk and talk during theirs.

It needs to be noted that in this passage Paul is addressing those who are living and who will continue to be so into the foreseeable future. He is trying to fill them will the same confidence he has, that NOTHING will separate them from God's love, and that NOTHING will interfere with the process of conformation that he has begun in them, which is why he says, "**If God be for us, who can be against us?**"

It also needs to be noted that in 1 John 3:2, quoted in the OP, John is addressing those who, unlike him, had never seen Jesus in the flesh, and that he is comforting these with the knowledge the THEY WILL see him, and can have the same confidence expressed by Job, who said:

> <sup>25</sup>For I know that my redeemer liveth, and that he shall stand at the latter day upon the earth: <sup>26</sup>And though after my skin worms destroy this body, yet in my flesh shall I see God: <sup>27</sup>Whom I shall see for myself, and mine eyes shall behold, and not another; though my reins be consumed within me.
>   *-- Job 19:25-27 (KJV)*

### Conclusion

The process of being "**conformed to the image of his Son**" has nothing to do with looking like Jesus, and everything to do with allowing the Spirit of God to move each saint as he moved Jesus:

> <sup>29</sup>And he that sent me is with me: the Father hath not left me alone; for I do always those things that please him.
>   -- John 8:29 (KJV)

To "be like Jesus", then, one would have to be moved by the same Spirit that moved him, and thereby learn of the Father and endeavour to do always what pleases Him.

---

Notes:

1. saint - one who has been (not alive), is being (alive), or will be (not yet alive) conformed to the image of Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

This answer premises that two combined principles creates the process in which one becomes "Like Christ". Similar to seed requires dirt. The dirt is the understood and practiced knowledge of the "Fear of the Lord". The seed is understanding and acting on the "Command of Love". What one learns from the commitment to the principles of the Fear of the Lord combined with commitment to the "Command of Love" is the developing process of "Like Jesus". John 15:4 Abide in me, and I in you. As the branch cannot bear fruit of itself, except it abide in the vine; no more can ye, except ye abide in me.

The Fear of the Lord is begging of knowledge, *"Prov. 1:7   The fear of the LORD is the beginning of knowledge: but fools despise wisdom and instruction."* To understand the fear of lord find *Prov 2:5 "Then shalt thou **understand the fear of the LORD, and find the knowledge of God."***

Then **understand** Proverbs 2:1-5 and begin to practice those principles.

From this point find John 13:21 *"He that hath my commandments, and keepeth them, he it is that loveth me: and he that loveth me shall be loved of my Father, and I will love him, and will **manifest myself to him.*** 22 Judas saith unto him, not Iscariot, Lord, how is it that thou wilt manifest thyself unto us, and not unto the world? *23 Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my words: and my Father will love him, **and we will come unto him, and make our abode with him.*** 24 He that loveth me not keepeth not my sayings: and the word which ye hear is not mine, but the Father’s which sent me.

Understand- **Love**- It's command and commitment to one who follows it. Seeing also the work of the Holy Spirit with in the command.  The Command is the bases of John 13-15 and 1,2,3 John

Through this the Mystery of the Gospel, that is "Christ In Us" will be made known to you.